# Trouble building Orchard on a Team Foundation Service Build Controller

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to setup a Team Foundation Service Build of Orchard and auto deploy to Azure. The structure of Orchard comes by default with the source and lib directories as siblings. The solution file does NOT directly reference the lib files.

.\lib(modules)(files)
.\src\solution.sln
.\src(projects)(files)

When executing a build on the Elastic Build of Team Foundation Service, the build errors report that none of the library files can be found. It appears that they are not being downloaded during the Get Source operation even though the workspace mapping is at the parent directory of lib and src. Without visibility into the build server, I cannot verify that.

Does anybody have any ideas on the cause?
Any way to force verify the lib files are downloaded for the build?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious mistake on my part, some of the dlls were excluded from source control and therefore were never downloaded. :-(  A gentle reminder to verify all assumptions.

Comment: Had the exact same issue... did checking in all the dlls from the lib folder take care of your problem?